# Thingsboard widget coding - how to access the data of the device (telemetry, etc) with HTML?

Tags: html, angular, widget, thingsboard

I'm trying to make a "latest values"-type widget with a simple table that displays telemetry of the datasource device(s). Here's the HTML code that makes it happen:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>//////</th>
    <th>ONLINE?</th>
    <th>OPEN/CLOSED?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Valve 1</th>
    <td>Y/N</td>
    <td>Open/Closed</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Valve 2</th>
    <td>Y/N</td>
    <td>Open/Closed</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Valve 3</th>
    <td>Y/N</td>
    <td>Open/Closed</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

For now, the Y/N and "Open/Closed" are placeholders. Instead of these strings, a real telemetry data should be displayed, updated in real time.

How do I access the telemetry data from the widget's datasource(s) in HTML? Is it possible without using Angular, or is Angular a must?

Answer (score 0):

For reference take a look at some of the default widgets from ThingsBoard e.g. the Simple Card Widgets.

The HTML section is blank and filled dynamically with the JavaScript Code. To add HTML elements `self.ctx.$container.append()` is used.

[image]